# Perl Device::SerialPort

Tags: linux, perl, serial-port, tty

Looking for right way to detect one keyword during board boot up message.
After keyword detected, send Enter key after one second.
Kernel is Linux.

```
# Serial port inisialisation is finished here.

# Read boot message
($count, $result) = $ob->read(300); # at least 300 chars coming till keyword appear

if ($result =~ m/Booting_up/) {
    print "send Enter ...\n";
    sleep 1;
    $ob->write("\r\n");
}
```

Thanks for hint

Comment: Maybe this is clear to all but -- what is the question?  What is `$ob->read`?

Comment: $ob->read prints the right boot up message however it missed that keyword most of the time. In putty console, user have to press Enter once he sees that keyword to come to device config menu, otherwise booting up continues normally (similar like PC restart then user press F2 to enter BIOS menu). . Is perl too slow so react?

Comment: Thanks for the explantion. But ... what class/module is it?  What does `read` method return? You are reading into two variables -- which gets what? What does it mean "_missed that keyword_"?  If it gets the message with the keyword how does it miss it?

Comment: Can `read` supply a line at a time, as it is printed?  Then you can do `while (read(...))` and check for the message, as each line is received.  For example.  Can you let us know what class/module `$ob` is from? Or can you clarify what/how `read` does?

Comment: Hi, this is my first serial port script, so not able to comment further. Now I can stop the boot message by sending "\n" from beginning (not detecting the Booting_up keyword). The effect is still same, to stop the boot message.

But now see strange behaviour after sending that $ob->write("\n\n") I can not send more than 16 characters with the subsequent $ob->write

    `$ob->write("\n\n");
    sleep 3;
    $ob->write("cmd"); // cmd length only 16 chars`

Comment: OK.  This, `$ob->read`, this is an object of some class which comes from some module, correct?  The `$ob` was created somehow -- I am asking what that module is -- like, `my $ob = Some::Name->new(...);` or some such. This would help because then I can look up what `read` does and may be able to help.

Comment: oh sorry forget to give the link i read:
[link](http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol4_1/tpj0401-0020.html)

Comment: Ah!  Thank you, that should help.  It is very late here so I'll look at it tomorrow at some time and come back here.

Comment: I posted something for you to try, but -- what do you mean by "_Kernel is Linux_"?  The link you offer is about `Win32::SerialPort`, not Linux.

Comment: Please *state the question in the title*.

Comment: This question makes me consider a cool little boot analysis raspberry pie appliance that you attach to the console port of systems that aren't booting completely.  Oh that Raspberry pi, what a "guy."

Comment: Discussion/clarification has been faint, and question quality is not high, though there are interesting answers.  Hopefully it improves.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using [Win32::SerialPort](http://search.cpan.org/~bbirth/Win32-SerialPort-0.22/lib/Win32/SerialPort.pm) module, or perhaps [Device::SerialPort](http://search.cpan.org/~cook/Device-SerialPort-1.002/SerialPort.pm) which

> provides an object-based user interface essentially identical to the one provided by the Win32::SerialPort module.

Its method `read` takes the number of bytes to read and returns the number read and writes them into the given string.

You may be "*missing*" the phrase because it's past the 300-mark, and your code doesn't read any further. Try to loop, getting a few bytes at a time and adding them up, thus building the string in small reads.

```
my bytes_in = 10;    # length of pattern, but it does NOT ensure anything
my ($read, $result);

while (1) 
{
    my ($count, $read) = $ob->read( $bytes_in ); 

    $result = $result . $read;
    if ($result =~ m/Booting_up/) {  # is it "Booting_up" or "Booting up" ?
        print "send Enter ...\n";
        sleep 1;                     # is this needed?
        $ob->write("\r\n");
        # last;                      # in case this is all you need to do
    }

    last if $count != $bytes_in;     # done reading 
}
```

I don't put the `$ob->read` statement in the loop condition since the documentation isn't crystal clear on how the method works.  You may also be able to simply use

```
while ( my ($count, $read) = $ob->read( $bytes_in ) ) {
    $result = $result . $read;
    if ($result =~ m/Booting_up/s) { 
        # ...
    }
    last if $count != $bytes_in;
}
```

We read a small number of bytes at a time to prevent problems with either *polling* or *blocking* reads, brought up in comments by [BenPen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2129481/benpen). See [Configuration and capability methods](http://search.cpan.org/~bbirth/Win32-SerialPort-0.22/lib/Win32/SerialPort.pm#Configuration_and_Capability_Methods).

You can first read those first 300 bytes that precede the pattern in one go and then start reading a few (or one) at a time, which would also lead to the quickest identification of the phrase.

This can be tweaked further but let's first see what it does as it stands (I cannot test).

Documentation also offers a few other methods which may be useful, in particular `readline` and `streamline`.  As this is all rather low level there are yet other ways but if you got all else working perhaps this will be enough to complete it.

Comment: The first block of code here might not do what we expect.   The exit condition doesn't seem correct.  I don't know exactly how read(300) behaves, but it either returns fewer bytes when the file is closed or  when there's a pause and there aren't 300 bytes to read since the last read()....  Either way, the loop exit doesn't sound right, since the serial port will never close itself...

Comment: From the documentation: Because all the tied methods block, they should ALWAYS be used with timeout settings and are not suitable for background operations and polled loops. The sysread method may return fewer characters than requested when a timeout occurs. The method call is still considered successful. If a sysread times out after receiving some characters, the actual elapsed time may be as much as twice the programmed limit. If no bytes are received, the normal timing applies.

Comment: @BenPen  While the docs don't say much, they do say that `$count` is the number of bytes read and offer an example which is pretty much my `last ...` statement.  So I think loop exit is fine.  What isn't clear is whether the `$result` is filled, but one would have to try.

Comment: @BenPen  Why do you quote tied methods?  Is `read` one of those?  It doesn't appear to be.  As for timeouts, that's a different concern.  The OP doesn't offer details.  The only clear thing is that it likely doesn't read enough data.  I'll wait for clarification on how this works (or doesn't).

Comment: Well, if you look at the I/O modes, there is polling, or blocking.  blocking read waits until 300 bytes to be ready, and poling returns immediately with all the bytes it has.  Both are problematic, right?  One blocks on the last 300 bytes if the output pauses, the other exits the loop too soon, mostly.

Comment: The timeouts section is enlightening.  http://search.cpan.org/~bbirth/Win32-SerialPort-0.22/lib/Win32/SerialPort.pm#Configuration_and_Capability_Methods

Comment: @BenPen  Sure, there is a whole lot more.  Like I say in the answer, it is rather low level.  I'd really read a few bytes at a time, patch the total read, and search that. However there is no detail in OP so I think that all we can do is wait for response and clarifications.  (I have to assume that they got the configuration down.)

Comment: That's cool.  At that point, blocking would be a better setting, but both would probably work.

Comment: @BenPen  Thanks for the suggestion, I did something along those lines. (The original 9 was a miscounted lenght, thanks for bringing it up :)  Note that editing posts so to change/add phrases or language is usually a tricky business (which is probably why they rejected it) -- but thank you for the attempt to improve the post!

Comment: Yeah, there's plenty of learning curve left for me...  I try to not care overly about the strangeness of Reputation gathering, but it's a meritocracy around here, so meh, gotta get on the same page to not be stuck as a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps rather index the string?

```
($count, $result) = $ob->read(300); # at least 300 chars coming till keyword appear

$substring = 'Booting_up';
 if (index($result, $substring) != -1) {
   print "send Enter ..\n";
   sleep 1;
   $ob->write("\r\n");
}
```